# Npm throws 'must have a URL that starts with http: or https:' when installing @angular2-material packages

Tags: npm, angular-material

I'm installing @angular2-material/core ( or any other module ) with npm wont let me install any of the modules.

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "@angular2-material/core"
npm ERR! node v5.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6

npm ERR! must have a URL that starts with http: or https:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

I've tried :

```
 npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ // https
```

OR

```
npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ // http
```

But It wont work , I raised the issue with material guys but they're saying this is my local issue .

This is really killing me , there is no clue how to fix it at all.

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/720

Comment: did you means you tired

Comment: did you means you tired   npm config set registry.?  sorry I was just trying to dig out whether npm set is equivalent to nam config set.. but I could not find proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly because you've tried multiple registries and now npm is kind of confused , You need to open your .npmrc and remove unnecessary registry paths.

To find your .npmrc :

```
     npm config ls -l | grep config
```

You will see something like :

```
     userconfig /Users/Yourname/.npmrc
```

Then open that file with your editor and edit and remove extra unnecessary registries .